# Is there a way to get the output messages from SQL Server when accessing the same DB using SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am wondering why a stored procedure (no parameters) isn't running when using SQL Alchemy. I execute the SP using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (Windows Authentication for login), I have verified I have execute rights, and of course it runs just fine.

[image: Output messages from MSSM]

When I run the same SP using SQL Alchemy it does not perform the tasks. I am hoping to find a way to read the output messages in my python code. Here is the connection setup and code executing the SP.

#---------------------------------------------

## MYDATABASE connection setup

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle
import urllib

MYDATABASE_params = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};' \
         'SERVER=MYSERVER;' \
         'PORT=1234;' \
         'DATABASE=MYDATABASE;' \
         'Trusted_Connection=yes;'

MYDATABASE_params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(MYDATABASE_params)

MYDATABASE_engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % MYDATABASE_params, echo=True)
```

#---------------------------------------------
How I'm executing the SP

```
archive_trig = "EXEC SCD_ENS_RATE_SHEET"
MYDATABASE_engine.execute(archive_trig)
```

No error is thrown in python but nothing happens in the DB. I have suspicions that it's permissions issue, when I run "sp_who2" on the DB in python, I get the same results as when I run it from MSSM except for the "ProgramName" column. It says Python for that result.

Any way to get the output messages in Python would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

The SP truncates the table and does some other stuff. When I run it from Python the table is in the same state and nothing has happened. When I run it from MSSM, it's truncated and the SP has clearly run.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the proc.

Comment: You have some oracle stuff in your code but the driver is MSSQL. Is the script really correct?

Comment: You're setting `echo=True`, do you set `autocommit=True` anywhere? Or [invoke](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#commit-as-you-go) `MYDATABASE_engine.commit()`?